# Tension of a string on a rotating sphere and under the influence of gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, string, centrifugal-force

I was studying about circular motion and found a topic that is apparent weight and found an equation of apparent value of g.

[image: HERE IS THE IMAGE OF EQUATION]

But I can't understand why this is written

[image: SEE IMAGE]

Comment: see the diagram-the body is rotating with our earth and the rotational motion leads to a centrifugal force in earth's frame of reference, therefore the body will experience two forces-one due to g and another due to w^2r and the resultant of two forces is effective wt.

Comment: do you mean to say that the calue of resultant is less than its constituent vectors. Why??

Comment: Related and all you need to do is use the cosine rule to get a relationship between the three sides of the vector triangle. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/328618/104696

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the force diagram at the equator from the inertial coordinate system:

$mg-N= m\omega^2R$.

So $mg>m\omega^2R$ or $g>\omega^2R$.

Obviously $2g>\omega^2R$.

This is a necessity to keep us from flying off the earth.

Comment: You are right but will there be further more explanation.

Comment: The first equation is the second law for a body in circular motion with angular velocity $\omega$. The other two equations are just some arithmetic. The final statement provides the physical basis. Could you say which part requires additional explanation?